# How to remove an enum item from an array

Tags: c#, .net, enums

In C#, how can I remove items from an enum array?

Here is the enum:

```
public enum example
{
    Example1,
    Example2,
    Example3,
    Example4
}
```

Here is my code to get the enum:

```
var data = Enum.GetValues(typeof(example));
```

How can I remove `Example2` from the data variable? I have tried to use LINQ, however I am not sure that this can be done.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot remove it from the array itself, but you can create a new array that does not have the `Example2` item:

```
var data = Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(example))
    .Cast<example>()
    .Where(item => item != example.Example2)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 8):

> I have tried to use LINQ, however I am not sure that this can be done.

**If you just want to exclude Example2**

```
var data = Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(example))
    .Cast<example>()
    .Where(item => item != example.Example2);
```

**If you want to exclude two or more enums**

```
var data = Enum.GetValues(typeof(example))
    .Cast<example>()
    .Except(new example[] { example.Example2, example.Example3 });
```